# ng-view is not displaying the pages but controller is working

Tags: angularjs

My code is below:

https://plnkr.co/edit/p3lgYwMRgSg7UHNLLAP9?p=info

I cannot get the partial in main.html to display when i open the link. I tried different browsers and its the same issue. I can see in the console log that the controller is being invoked. I'm just not sure why my ngView isnt working.

Index file:

```
    !DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="Computer">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Computer Solutions</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <!-- The justified navigation menu is meant for single line per list item.
           Multiple lines will require custom code not provided by Bootstrap. -->
      <div class="masthead">
        <h3 class="text-muted">Computer Solutions</h3>
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav nav-justified">
            <li>
              <a href="#/main">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="about.html">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="services.html">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>

      <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div ng-view></div>
      </div>

      <!-- Site footer -->
      <footer class="footer">
        <p>© 2015 Company, Inc.</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
    <!-- /container -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

script.js file

```
 var app = angular.module("Computer", ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.
    when('/main',{
      templateURL: 'main.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    }).
    otherwise({redirectTo:'/main'})
}])

.controller('MainCtrl',[function(){
  console.log('This is 111the MainCtrl');
}]);
```

main.html

```
<!-- Jumbotron -->
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="http://techguystaging.com/files/computer-icon.png">
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-8">
        <h1>Computer Solutions</h1>
        <p class="lead">Get your stuff fixed here.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Example row of columns -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <h2>Hardware Repairs</h2>
      <p>Get your CPU fixed here along with your other tech stuff </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <h2>Virus Removal</h2>
      <p>Destroy those trojan horses and worms</p>
   </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <h2>System Tune up</h2>
      <p>Faster better stronger.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly get rid of the `ng-controller` line in `index.html` as the controller is instantiated by the route definition (you don't have to explicitly load it).

The reason why the plunk seems to not be working is the relative url string of `main.html`. Change it to this and it should work:

```
$routeProvider.
    when('/main',{
       templateUrl: './main.html',
       controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
```

I have created and update plunk here: https://plnkr.co/edit/uTGiDCF18J0fvQpg1It1?p=preview

Comment: Thanks that was helpful!